# Specifying bigquery table schema that resides on a file in a multipart http request

Tags: database, python-2.7, multipart, google-bigquery

I have a text file schema.txt in which the schema for the table that I want to create is defined.

I want to include this file in the multipart HTTP request that I'm using to create my table.

How do I specify the schema.txt file in the multipart HTTP request?

Below is what I'm currently doing (not working though):

```
def loadTable(service, projectId, datasetId, targetTableId, sourceCsv, filenm):
try:
    jobCollection = service.jobs()
    jobData = {
        'projectId': projectId,
        'configuration': {
            'load': {
                'sourceUris': [sourceCsv],
                'schema': filenm,
                'destinationTable': {
                    'projectId': projectId,
                    'datasetId': datasetId,
                    'tableId': targetTableId
                },
                'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                'encoding': 'UTF-8'
             }
        }
    }
```

Where `filenm` will be 'schema.txt'.

I know I can specify the schema directly as:

```
'schema': {
    'fields': [
               {
                   'name': 'level',
                   'type': 'STRING',
               },
               {
                   'name': 'message',
                   'type': 'STRING',
               }
              ]
           },
```

But instead I want to specify the file containing the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure why you need a "multipart HTTP request" unless you are ingesting directly from a file. Here you are specifying a CSV input, indicating a Cloud Storage object.

See here for more info:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#storageimport

In any case, this is not really a BigQuery question, more a Python question.. do you mean this?

```
import json

def loadTable(project_id, dataset_id, target_table, source_csv, filename):

  file = open(filename, 'r')
  schema = file.read()
  file.close()

  schema_json = json.loads('{%s}' % schema)

  job_data = {
    "projectId": project_id,
      "configuration": {
            "load": {
                "sourceUris": [source_csv],
                "schema": schema_json,
                "destinationTable": {
                    "projectId": project_id,
                    "datasetId": dataset_id,
                    "tableId": target_table
                },
                "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                "encoding": "UTF-8"
             }
        }
    }


  print json.dumps(job_data, indent=2)

loadTable('project_id', 'dataset_id', 'target_table', 'source_csv', '/tmp/schema.txt')
```